# C++ Win32 (WinAPI) Custom Window Frame with maximize button

Tags: c++, winapi, window, frame

I'm trying to customize a window frame using c++ win32 like Adobe products specifically Photoshop. With minimize, maximize, and close button.

Can someone give me an example for doing this or can someone show me how to do it

Sorry for being noob.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can look at the MSDN for the steps and some examples on how to do it.  Maybe that can point you in the right direction.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx